# SQL unpivoting columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to unpivot table:

```
+------+-----+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
| YEAR | SEC | DEPT |                            TITLE                             | M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 | M5 | M6 | M7 | M8 | M9 | M10 | M11 | M12 |
+------+-----+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2002 | C   |   30 | Other transport equipment                                    |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |
| 2002 | C   |   31 | Furniture manufacturing                                      |  2 |  2 |  2 |  2 |  2 |  2 |  2 |  2 |  2 |   2 |   2 |   2 |
| 2002 | C   |   32 | Other manufacturing                                          |  3 |  3 |  3 |  3 |  3 |  3 |  3 |  3 |  3 |   3 |   3 |   3 |
| 2002 | D   |   30 | Repair and installation of machinery and equipment           |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |   4 |   4 |   4 |
| 2002 | D   |   31 | Electricity, gas, steam and air conditioning                 |  5 |  5 |  5 |  5 |  5 |  5 |  5 |  5 |  5 |   5 |   5 |   5 |
| 2002 | D   |   32 | Water collection, treatment and supply                       |  6 |  6 |  6 |  6 |  6 |  6 |  6 |  6 |  6 |   6 |   6 |   6 |
| 2002 | E   |   30 | Waste collection, treatment and disposal; materials recovery |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |   7 |   7 |   7 |
| 2002 | E   |   31 | Remediation activities and other waste management services   |  8 |  8 |  8 |  8 |  8 |  8 |  8 |  8 |  8 |   8 |   8 |   8 |
| 2002 | E   |   32 | Construction of buildings                                    |  9 |  9 |  9 |  9 |  9 |  9 |  9 |  9 |  9 |   9 |   9 |   9 |
+------+-----+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

to this:

```
+------+-------+-----+------+---------------------------+-------+
| YEAR | MONTH | SEC | DEPT |           TITLE           | COUNT |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------------------------+-------+
| 2002 |     1 | C   |   30 | Other transport equipment |     1 |
| 2002 |     1 | C   |   31 | Furniture manufacturing   |     2 |
| 2002 |     1 | C   |   32 | Other manufacturing       |     3 |
| 2002 |     2 | C   |   30 | Other transport equipment |     1 |
| 2002 |     2 | C   |   31 | Furniture manufacturing   |     2 |
| 2002 |     2 | C   |   32 | Other manufacturing       |     3 |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------------------------+-------+
```

What I have so far is :

```
select YEAR, SEC, DEPT,TITLE, MONTH
from mytable u
unpivot
(
  MONTH for mj in ([M1]
      ,[M2]
      ,[M3]
      ,[M4]
      ,[M5]
      ,[M6]
      ,[M7]
      ,[M8]
      ,[M9]
      ,[M10]
      ,[M11]
      ,[M12] )
) u;
```

but this is giving me count for all months. I need  this with month number and count value for that month. Values 1-9 could be any numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with

```
    SELECT YEAR, SEC, DEPT,TITLE, MONTH, TOTAL
FROM 
(SELECT YEAR, SEC, DEPT,TITLE
      ,M1
      ,M2
      ,M3
      ,M4
      ,M5
      ,M6
      ,M7
      ,M8
      ,M9
      ,M10
      ,M11
      ,M12
FROM db.dbo.mytable pvt) p
UNPIVOT
    (TOTAL FOR MONTH IN
    ( M1
      ,M2
      ,M3
      ,M4
      ,M5
      ,M6
      ,M7
      ,M8
      ,M9
      ,M10
      ,M11
      ,M12)) AS unpvt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT mt.[YEAR], mt.[SEC], mt.DEPT, mt.TITLE, mval as Month_Val
FROM mytable mt CROSS APPLY 
     ( VALUES ([M1], 'Jan'), ([M2], 'Feb'), . . . , ([M12], 'Dec') 
     ) mtt([MONTH], mval);
```

Comment: Ok, I have months now, but I need to keep values for each month in separate columns as well. How do I do that?